# Check if Python input contains a specific word

Tags: python

This is just INPUT/OUTPUT coding
What is does: You type in "Area" or "perimeter" or "volume" and it will ask for certain strings and calculates it. This code checks for the length and if the input contains numbers, and if it is over the length It will print the error.

OBJECTIVE: If "Area", "perimeter" or "volume" is in the input, proceed to the next function..

```
print ("This program will find the area, perimeter and volume of the Rectangle!")

    find = input ("Type in one to calculate "area", "perimeter"  and volume": ")

    if len(find) == 4 and find.isalpha():   #This is area, people can type 4 chars and can get away with it, is there a way to fix it?
        w = int (input ("What is the Width of the rectangle: "))
        l = int (input ("What is the Length of the rectangle: "))
        a = w*l
        ans = "The area of the rectangle is %s units!"
        print (ans%(a))
    elif len (find) == 6 and  find.isalpha():   # This is Volume
        w = int(input ("What is the Width of the rectangle: "))
        l = int(input ("What is the Length of the rectangle: "))
        h = int(input ("What is the Height of the rectangle: "))
        v = l*w*h
        ans = "The volume of the rectangle is %s units!"
        print (ans%(v))
    elif len (find) == 9 and find.isalpha():  #This is  Perimeter
        w = int (input ("What is the Width of the rectangle: "))
        l = int (input ("What is the Length of the rectangle: "))
        p = 2*(l+w)
        ans = "The primeter of the rectangle is %s units!"
        print (ans%(p))
    else:
        print ("You spelled area, perimeter or volume wrong, or what you typed in includes NUMBERS!")
```

Comment: you have several issues. Check your quote marks `"` and if I enter 'blah' right now your code thinks it's 'area'...why not check `if find.lower() == 'area':`

Comment: This sounds like you just dumped your homework question. We're not at all opposed to helping with homework, but it *does* need to be a [mcve]. You haven't actually told us what your problem is. And as depperm pointed out here, you've got many. Actually most of the problems. This is almost entirely the wrong way to accomplish what you want.

Answer (score 5):

Just **compare** the string instead of checking it with length.

eg:

```
if find == "area":    #to check if the user input is "area"
```

and similarly for perimeter and volume.

Comment: you'll want it to be `find.lower()` just in case